# Appyling btn-link attribute to <a> in Bootstrap w/ focus

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I seem to be having some problems applying the btn-link attribute to a link with Bootstrap. According to the docs, button styles can be applied to anything with the button class. So if I have something like:

```
<a class="btn btn-link selected" name="test" href="#">Test</a>
```

It should apply the btn-link style to that respective link. This seems to work fine except for the "focus" attribute. If you look at the examples on the Bootstrap page [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#buttons), clicking on a button with the btn-link class results in a blue box appearing as a border. With the above HTML, this does not seem to be the case.

I can get it to show the blue border by forcing the element state to "focus" with Chrome dev-tools, but I cannot replicate it any other way. Using a selector and then applying a .focus() doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand what blue border you're talking about on `btn-link`.  `btn-link` for me just looks like any other `<a>` element.

Comment: After you click it, it looks like this http://i.imgur.com/7VjhDV1.png. That blue border is what I'm after.

Comment: So you just want a border to show up when the button is clicked?  For me, on the bootstrap example I get a dashed border, and it's not blue.

Comment: That was more or less what I was shooting for.

Comment: Any particular reason you have to use `btn-link` instead of something like `btn-primary`?  It's tough to say what action `focus` will take for you, because typically when clicking a button, something happens.  Is the page going to reload?  You can change its state on mousedown, or on click, but what are you trying to achieve by adding a border after its been clicked?

Comment: From my tests, if you just use a `<button>` element then you get the blue border you're looking for. `<button class="btn btn-link selected" name="test" href="#">Test</button>`